# Construction of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, definition, tensor-products

When defining the tensor product $V \otimes W$, we define this as the quotient space $Free(V \times W) / \mathcal{R}$ where $\mathcal{R} \subset Free(V \times W) $ is an appropiately chosen subspace of the free vector space which makes the mapping $ v \otimes w := \mu(v,w) := \pi_{Free(V \times W) / \mathcal{R}}((v,w))$ bilinear.

Why do we require the quotient space $\mathbb{R}\langle V \times W \rangle / \mathcal{R} := V \otimes W$  rather than just directly using the quotient space $(V \times W) / \mathcal{R}$? We would have $V \otimes W := (V \times W) / \mathcal{R}$, which is a vector space and we could then define a bilinear mapping $\mu(v,w) := v \otimes w$ in the same way as above.

Thanks.

Comment: $\mathcal{R}$, if defined on $V\times W$, is the whole space (if we're using the same definition of $\mathcal{R}$, as being generated by a few elements like $(v+\lambda v',w)-((v,w)+\lambda(v',w))=(0,-\lambda w)$, among some others), so $V\times W/\mathcal{R}=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** (Before I wrote everything wrong... twice)

Just look how the generators of $R$ would look like if $R\subset V\times W.$ If you want to repeat construction from $Free(V\times W)$ you would get that $R=V\times W$. In fact:
$$(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)=(v_1+v_2,w+w)$$
for example. So one generator of $R$ equals
$$(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)-(v_1+v_2,w)=(0,w).$$

Similarly we can recoevr every $(v,0).$ hence $R=V\times W.$

Notice that if $V,W$ have finite dimensions, then the space $Free(V\times W)$ is huge and $R$ is also huge. However $V\otimes W:=Free(V\times W)/R$ has dimension $\dim V\cdot\dim W.$

I guess you have problems with understanding this construction cause you do not have enought intuition of what $Free(V\times W)$ is. I reccomend you to convince yourself that $Free(V\times W)$ is quite a big space (hint: look at its base).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do you say it glues nothing? Does $R = V \times W$ not imply that everything is in the same equivalence class, since $$x \sim y ~~~\text{if}~~x-y \in R = V \times W$$ hence $$x \sim y ~~~\text{for all } ~~x,y \in V \times W,$$ does that not mean that everything is glued together?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I messed up a little bit. Actually $R=0.$ and you are right we glue everything.

Comment: @Alex Cause a priori we do not know $R.$ We define it such that it is generated by elements $(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)-(v_1+v_2,w)$ and others. And then we get that $x\sim y$ if $x-y\in R.$ But we showed that $R=0$ so $x\sim y$ if $x=y.$ So we actually glue nothing (above I mistaken).

Comment: uhmmm..so from Luiz Corderio's comment above we would get $\mathcal{R} = V \times W$ based on the usual generators for the tensor product, and hence $(V \times W)/ \mathcal{R} = 0$, this seems right to me. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @Alex I do not agree. If we start with abstract relation defined by
$$(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)\sim(v_1+v_2,w),$$
it really means that $x\sim y$ if and for some $v_1,v_2,w$
$$x=(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)\wedge y=(v_1+v_2,w).$$
But this holds if and only if $x=y.$
Given any set $X$ and equivalence relation on it such that $x\sim y$ iff $x=y$ we get that set of classes is again $X,$ cause we glued nothing.

Comment: @Alex Everything I wrote is wrong. Sorry I will fix it.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your help. I was adding vectors from $V\times W$stupidly, hence I got stupid results.

Comment: No prob, I think the reasoning is clear now, thanks.